# Is it possible to stream/map a series of values in to one result, through a dot notation method?

Tags: java, java-stream

I am trying to do something like this.

```
public static int generateKey(Collection<Column> currentColumns, Object entry) {
    int hash = 0;
    for (Column c : currentColumns) { 
        hash = Objects.hash(hash, c.getHashValue(entry));
    }
    return hash;
}
```

But I know that `Objects.hash()` can take many parameters as it's dot notation so I'm wondering if I can stream from `currentColumns` collection, each result from `getHashValue()` in to the `Objects.hash` method?

My attempts are not worth sharing as I couldn't find any guidance on if this is possible.

edit - For some real world contex, I am doing something like an SQL query on a Collection of Entry Objects to generate an gorupBy / aggregate summary, and any part of the object that is grouped by will need to be keyed off of, so I am using this thing to generate a key for a groupingBy collector. If my results are over a certain length, then columns get removed to try and reduce the number of rows, and will then retry this with a reduced column set.

Comment: What stops you from using `myObjects.hashCode()` and then implement `hashCode`correctly  in `MyObject()`

Comment: This is a simplified example, the structure of what i'm doing is more complex, i'm actually passing parameters in to getAValue, it's not a simple hash.

Comment: Then please provide a more accurate real-world example, not saying you that you need to add all your code, but this small method call with arguments makes a big difference, when trying to answer your question

Comment: Or please give me some credit, or try and answer the question I've asked. I didn't ask  how I could make a hash code, I asked how I could use streams to funnel some mapped results in to a dot notation, variable argument style function.

Comment: I didn't meant to come over as rude, but the more information you include into your question the more likely is that it will get answered with a usable solution. Currently the way I think of, could be using `Stream.reduce()` like this: `int hash = myObjects.stream().reduce(0, (h, o) -> Objects.hash(h, o.getAValue(), Integer::sum);`. Though I am not sure if it will work because you didn't provide more information

Comment: It's sort of tough to take the larger thing i'm attempting and reduce to a simple example. But I have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a vararg is basically a syntactic sugar for an array, you could do something like this:

```java
Object[] array = myObjects.stream().map(MyObject::getAValue).toArray();
int hash = Objects.hash(array);
```